# How do i identify the compound/complex fields in salesforce discover api objects

Tags: apex, custom-field, compound-fields

I am using Stitch to load data into an outside database and we keep seeing the following error:

Error syncing Opportunity: InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: FUNCTIONALITY_NOT_ENABLED: Selecting compound data not supported in Bulk Query

How can Identify what fields on an object are compound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ByteLength,DataType,DefaultValueFormula,DeveloperName,Digits,DurableId,EntityDefinitionId,ExtraTypeInfo,FieldDefinitionId,Id,InlineHelpText,IsApiFilterable,IsApiGroupable,IsApiSortable,IsAutonumber,IsCalculated,IsCaseSensitive,IsCompactLayoutable,IsComponent,IsCompound,IsCreatable,IsDefaultedOnCreate,IsDependentPicklist,IsDeprecatedAndHidden,IsDisplayLocationInDecimal,IsEncrypted,IsFieldHistoryTracked,IsHighScaleNumber,IsHtmlFormatted,IsIdLookup,IsLayoutable,IsListVisible,IsNameField,IsNamePointing,IsNillable,IsPermissionable,IsUnique,IsUpdatable,IsWorkflowFilterable,IsWriteRequiresMasterRead,Label,Length,Mask,MaskType,MasterLabel,Name,NamespacePrefix,Precision,QualifiedApiName,ReferenceTargetField,ReferenceTo,RelationshipName,RelationshipOrder,Scale,ServiceDataTypeId,ValueTypeId FROM EntityParticle where EntityDefinitionId = 'Opportunity' and IsCompound = false AND FieldDefinitionId IN (
SELECT DurableId FROM 
FieldDefinition
where IsCompound = true)
```

I believe this query does the trick!

Comment: ^ that query overlooks Compound fields built of other Compound fields.

When I run it on my org, I get 2 records.

When I cut out the unneeded and "IsCompound = false" from the first row of the SOQL, I get three records.

Comment: briefly: SELECT Label, MasterLabel, Name FROM EntityParticle WHERE EntityDefinitionId = 'Opportunity' AND FieldDefinitionId IN (SELECT DurableId FROM FieldDefinition WHERE IsCompound = TRUE)